# Grant user read/write permissions for files in /sys

Tags: permissions

Running gentoo AMD64 here and cannot figure out how to grant an ordinary user read and write permissions to some files in /sys/ I know that /sys/ is dynamic and is not a real directory but is made at boot. Even if thats not the case how do I grant permissions for files in /sys/?

Comment: What's the intention?

Comment: I don't know what the OPs intention is/was, but I would like to be able to do gpio stuff using the facilities in /sys/class/gpio from a privileged, but non-root, user